# HttpError 404 for code that worked for years

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Python project/code using the YouTube V3 API. Everything was working fine for over 2 years now, but suddenly I keep getting HttpError 404 for any request I make.

For example: *HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?alt=json&part=contentDetails%2Csnippet%2Cstatistics&key=AIzaSyCtyf8jToJowBEhpNL37UU3EjW0QhowXc4&forUsername=Chessexplained returned "Not Found"*

The funny thing is, that if you open/click the link manually it works.
This is my code:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

DEVELOPER_KEY = mykey
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

service = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
request = service.channels().list(part = "contentDetails,snippet,statistics", forUsername=username)
```

Comment: [Error 404](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#NOT_FOUND) means that a resource associated with the request could not be found. If you have not used this API in the last two weeks, please re-deploy the App Engine app and try calling it again. You may also check this [related thread](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/9802).